# How can I join multiple large text files

Tags: notepad++

I have about 12,000 .txt files. Most about 10mb in size. I need to join them all into one large text file.  Mostly I use Notepad++ but the “combine” plug doesn’t work with it anymore. I’ve tried a couple freeware options but they freak out over the number and size.  And trying to use the windows command line copy option freaks out, again because there’s so many.  I know I could probably do a few at a time or just open each one and copy and paste into a file... but that will take forever.  Is there any other way?!

Comment: I think there are too much files and/or the result is too large for Npp. If you have a linux machine, you could do: `cat *.txt > result.txt`. A perl one-liner can also do the job,

Comment: Note that Windows 10 also has a [Bash shell](https://itsfoss.com/install-bash-on-windows/) now, s this

Answer (score 2):

If Notepad++ is not a hard requirement, you could use the `COPY` command to do this. This will copy the contents of all `.txt` files to a new file called `output`:

```
copy *.txt output
```

If that does not work for whatever reason, you could try a short script such as this (save as a `.bat` file in the same folder as the files you want to join):

```
if exist output del output

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    type "%%a" >> output
)
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post. I’ve tried the copy option, it does not work. It freaks out part way through because of the size and number of files.

Comment: @Jason, Ah, somehow I missed that. Could you try the script I added?

Comment: How far does copy get? If it can handle say 1k files from 12k then you only need 12 manual operations.

Answer (score 1):

As @Toto said in comments

> If you have a linux machine, you could do: `cat *.txt > result.txt`

Except that you no longer need a Linux box -  Windows 10 also has a Bash shell, so [install it](https://itsfoss.com/install-bash-on-windows/) and use the `cat` command with wildcards to match all  file names to be combined.